# Why use "ein" instead of "einen" in "Was für ein Mumpitz!"?

Tags: article

> Was für **ein** Mumpitz!

I'm not sure why you need to use "ein" here, as "Mumpitz" is a masculin noun and the preposition "für" should be followed by the accusative form "einen".

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10138/1224

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right "Mumpitz" is masculin. But you misinterpret the structure. It's not that something is done for the Mumpitz, or something similar.

> Was für ein Mumpitz

is short for

> Was ist das für ein Mumpitz

so here "was für ein" is synonmym to "welche Art", "welch ein" and that's why Mumpitz is in nominative case here.